# Twilio Outbound Status "in-progress" but audio is "ringing"

Tags: python, twilio, status, twilio-api

I'm creating python code to start and monitor a conference call. The code initiates calls to 2 or more numbers and directs them to a TwiML Bin conference:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Response>
  <Dial>
    <Conference
                beep="false"
                waitUrl="http://twimlets.com/holdmusic?Bucket=com.twilio.music.ambient"
                >
      Conf
    </Conference>
  </Dial>
</Response>
```

This works great for some numbers, but others are showing as "in-progress" before the call is picked up by the recipient. The problem with this is that the instant they indicate "in-progress", they are placed into the conference and the ringing sounds play into the conference. I end up with a conference full of ringing phones.

I've tried with different phone numbers, some work just fine, some don't. The same numbers that don't work, always don't work, it's not intermittent. I've tried using a TwiML Bin redirect to the conference, but it still just redirects when ringing.

Is there a trick I'm missing here with the TwiML Bin to properly categorized a call? It seems to me that it might just be a result of certain phone systems not being sophisticated enough to tell Twilio "ringing"?

**In summary:**
I expect Twilio to be able to understand that a phone is ringing, vs having been answered, but "ringing" is making it through as "in-progress" for come recipient phone numbers. This causes issues with ringing phones into the conference and also charges my account for calls that were never completed.

Comment: This is odd behaviour and not something we are likely to be able to solve on Stack Overflow. I would recommend contacting the [Twilio support team](https://www.twilio.com/help/contact), describing this issue and sharing any relevant call SIDs that you can.

Comment: Okay, thanks @philnash

Comment: Hope you get it sorted!

Answer (score 0):

I received a response from Twilio after they looked into the specific call. They don't have any control over this specific issue because they're receiving a response from the recipient that says "I answered" before they actually answered.

"Twilio will change the status to in-progress when we receive a SIP 200 OK response from the far end. So it would seem that the far end carrier (Zipwhip ) responds with a 200 OK before the actual device itself answers the call. I am afraid that Twilio does not have any control over this."